# Radio Telescope Rx/Tx resolution

Tags: radio

Very simple question. If (say) a 65m radiotelescope obeserving at 5cm (6GHz) has a resolution of about 1mRad, if it becomes a transmitter at that frequency does it radiate a beam of the same divergence angle?
I think it probably does, but would like a second opinion

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The principle of [antenna reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_(electromagnetism)) applies.